# When used UIViewControllerRepresentable in SwiftUI, the UIHostingController was clip after navigation link

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, uihostingcontroller, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I try to use UIHostingController in UIViewControllerRepresentable inside SwiftUI NavigationView.

But I noticed a problem with this on **iOS 16** the content in HostinController clipped after being moved to another view in NavigationLink.

[Gif example](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExcTNmbmgzMjk0bW9zODk3aXp0Z3hneTRnbHJjcGh4NDk4eTk2ejZoeCZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/QSVWixg929bGJGDNKb/giphy.gif)

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    TosterView { Color.green }
                        .frame(height: 170)

                    NavigationLink(destination: { Text("Destination")}, label: { Text("Go to destination")})

                    Color.orange.frame(height: 900)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct TosterView<PageContent: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let contentForData: () -> PageContent

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<PageContent> {
        UIHostingController(rootView: contentForData())
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<PageContent>, context: Context) {}
}
```

P.S. Please don't recommend to use UIViewRepresentable or use ViewController with background Green

Comment: I checked your code in iOS 17.0 iPhone 15 pro simulator. It works fine. It didn't clip the green view.

Comment: @MahiAlJawad Are you serious? I wrote that this problem on iOS 16!

Comment: Yes. I checked on iOS 17 simulator. Try it.

Comment: @MahiAlJawad But I need to fix it on iOS 16!